# RxJava - single thread asynchronous processing

Tags: java, asynchronous, rx-java2

I have a question. Is possible run two tasks asynchronously in single threaded environment in RxJava? I know that Java should contain library for this functionality, but i think that RxJava does not contain it.

Comment: Why do you want this? What is your use case?

Comment: Question is bounded to Java threading. Is Java capable performs 2 tasks asynchronously only with main thread without using some library? I think that not due to existency of AsyncTask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it contains single threaded asynchronous processing at it contains any thread count processing.

Example

```
Flowable.fromCallable(() ->{
            // do something
        })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.single());
```

Alternatives to `Schedulers.single()` is `Schedulers.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1))` where you can specify thread pool

Comment: Main thread + single thread = 2.I read about features of other programming languages which enable asynchrounous processing of tasks with only one thread, but it is not probably case of Java.

Comment: Oh ok, I misunderstood your question. That's not available in Java but you can check Kotlin coroutines https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines.html

Comment: There is a blocking scheduler implementation in [the extensions project](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#blockingscheduler). However, if you are using it with blocking IO for example, you stop your entire application with it.