# RxJava Rx is single-threaded by default. Really?

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java, rx-java2

Hi I found few manuals state: **Rx is single-threaded by default.**

You can find this phrase here https://github.com/Froussios/Intro-To-RxJava/blob/master/Part%204%20-%20Concurrency/1.%20Scheduling%20and%20threading.md but this is not just one place to get it from.

I tried to play a bit with it and got it multi-threaded actually. Here simple code I tried with:

```
    Observable<Long> values1 = Observable.interval(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    values1.subscribe(
        v -> {
            System.out.println("Received 1: " + v + ", Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        },
        e -> System.out.println("Error: " + e),
        () -> System.out.println("Completed")
    );

    Observable<Long> values2 = Observable.interval(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    values2.subscribe(
        v -> {
            System.out.println("Received 2: " + v + ", Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        },
        e -> System.out.println("Error: " + e),
        () -> System.out.println("Completed")
    );

    values1.subscribe(
            v -> {
                System.out.println("Received 3: " + v + ", Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            },
            e -> System.out.println("Error: " + e),
            () -> System.out.println("Completed")
        );

    System.in.read();
```

Here just two observables and 3 readers. This code outputs:

```
Received 1: 0, Thread: RxComputationThreadPool-1
Received 3: 0, Thread: RxComputationThreadPool-3
Received 2: 0, Thread: RxComputationThreadPool-2
Received 1: 1, Thread: RxComputationThreadPool-1
Received 2: 1, Thread: RxComputationThreadPool-2
Received 3: 1, Thread: RxComputationThreadPool-3
...
```

as I see from output every reader takes new thread, and I never mentioned explicitly to create new thread for every new observer. So is this single threaded default behavior or not? Am I miss somewhere?

Comment: This is kind of related to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48267688/rxjava-single-thread-asynchronous-processing
RxJava implements a reactive behavior and as such it can operate (in a non-blocking way) with a single thread.

Comment: `found few manuals state`, in this case it would be prudent to provide references to the manuals.

Comment: As you can see in my question it not works in one thread, instead it creates new thread for every observer I started. More over the main thread, where they are started from, still exist too. So 3 observers application uses 1 main thread and 3 threads for observers. Not a single thread but 4.

Comment: I updated post with link. Please check.

Comment: RxJava is synchronous by default, which is not the same as single threaded. JavaScript and Node.js are single threaded. In RxJava, the asynchrony is explicitly defined via operators using Schedulers or implicitly in combinators working with arbitrary sources being potentially concurrent with respect to each other.

Comment: Do you mean the statement: "Rx is single-threaded by default" is wrong as RxJava is synchronous but it is not the same as single threaded? Can I know how you get this and where this difference explicitly described?

Answer (score 1):

RxJava is single-threaded has two parts to it:

1. Most operations are executed sequentially. This means that when the source produces a value it is immediately processed by the next step in the chain unless:

   - The operator is one of the asynchronous operators, which require delays and threads to work. Examples include `observeOn` and `interval`. Since your example uses `interval` which would require blocking to be truely single-threaded, the more efficient scheduler-based solution is used.
   - From memory the only operators that use blocking are the operators that convert from other formats that use blocking such as `Callable<T>` and `Future<T>`.
2. Most of the RxJava standard and operators assume that the input is *sequential*, this means that when you implement your own observable you need to make sure that calls to `onNext` do not happen in parallel. This is presumably what the rule "RxJava is single-threaded" is based on since it does not natively support parallel operations. `RxJava2` adds the `ParallelObservable` family of operations to support true parallelism.

Comment: Not sure understand this right. Some of observables cause observer to work in same thread and some of them cause to work in parallel thread. Right? Does this means every HTTP request or data base query observer will run in parallel thread? Seems like whatever object or method creates new threads should know what is observable data source or how long will it takes to get data. How could this be done?

Comment: How the HTTP request/database observable handles threads depends entirely on the library that implements it. An example is that Retrofit can create HTTP observables that execute on the `subscribe` thread as well as execute on a dedicated executor, depending on how it is configured. RxJava does not care as long as the protocol is followed. (No parallel calls to `onNext`, either `onSuccess` or `onError` etc)

Comment: In my example observable values1 calls two observer objects onNext method and they are run each in separate thread. From what you say does it mean that observer call these two observables onNext method from one thread while it not care on which threads observers are will execute?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that Observable.interval(), because it operates on a timer, it needs to run on a separate thread and will run on the computation Scheduler by default. So it allows multithreading by default